# c# проверка ссылки

Tags: c#

Есть код, который выводит изображение по ссылке:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string link;

        link = textBox1.Text;
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(link);


    }
```

Если ввести правильную ссылку (например P:\Database\Картинка.png, то изображение выводится корректно. Подскажите, как грамотно написать участок кода, который бы ловил пользователя на том, что он вводит что-то, отличное от ссылки, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оберните блок в try-catch:

```
try
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(link);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Файл не найден!");
}
catch (OutOfMemoryException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Формат файла не поддерживается!");
}
```

Посмотреть какие исключения и в каких случаях бросают методы можно на MSDN: [Image.FromFile (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Спасибо, именно такую реализацию я и искал! Но возникает ошибка, Ошибка 1  Не удалось найти имя типа или пространства имен "FileNotFoundException" (пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку?)

Comment: Как я понимаю, надо добавить что-то ещё в using?

Comment: Нужно добавить ссылку на сборку. Вроде, WindowsForms.Graphic

Comment: Пространство имен `System.IO` добавьте: [Класс FileNotFoundException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Да, не хватало пространства System.IO, всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно через регулярку:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    string link;
    link = textBox1.Text;
    string pattern = @"[^ ]+\.png|.jpeg";
    Regex rg = new Regex(pattern);
    if (!rg.IsMatch(link))
    {
        //Выдача предупреждения и возврат
        MessageBox.Show("НЕ ТО");
        return;
    }

    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(link);
}
```